# Why it is "be" here?

Tags: subjunctives

The original sentence:

> The administration of a strong sleeping draught to the condemned man
>   every night from which one night he does hot awake, seems a more
>   civilized alternative to our present barbarous procedure, if capital
>   punishment through the influence of backward minds **be** retained.

Is "be" supposed to be "were" here?

> The administration of a strong sleeping draught to the condemned man
>   every night from which one night he does hot awake, seems a more
>   civilized alternative to our present barbarous procedure, if capital
>   punishment through the influence of backward minds **were** retained.

Comment: Source of the text please.  This seems to be rather dated in its style.

Comment: For some reason, Google Books does not display the content on my PC. https://books.google.com/books?id=_-PzdXhnhLIC&pg=PA197&lpg=PA197&dq=%22The+administration+of+a+strong+sleeping+draught%22&source=bl&ots=xDQAMk4KzL&sig=ACfU3U3RFzEzOJw81CP3KB1b2LPOr2IX_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZ8N3YnLbiAhVNSK0KHbndAakQ6AEwAXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20administration%20of%20a%20strong%20sleeping%20draught%22&f=false.

Comment: But I found it from a different website. It's the 2nd word from the bottom in the article. https://studfiles.net/preview/4365502/page:9/

Comment: This is the link for the book on Amazon. https://www.amazon.com/moral-courage-Compton-Mackenzie/dp/B001G4Y91K